# Replacing dependent with independent RVs for Hoeffding inequality.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

Let $\bar Y= \frac 1n \sum_{i=1}^n Y_i$ where the $Y_i\in \{0,1\}$ are not necessarily independent, but where the marginals satisfy $\Pr[Y_i=1]\leq \Pr[X_i=1]$ for independent (but not identically distributed) Bernoulli variables $X_i$. My goal is to use Hoeffding-type bounds on $\bar Y$ by using $\bar X$ instead. It would suffice for my purposes to show that $$\Pr[\bar Y >t] \leq \Pr[\bar X>t]$$ where $\bar X$ is defined analogously to $\bar Y$. Intuitively, this should hold since each $X_i$ has a superior probability of being $1$. However, I was not able to show this rigorously. My question is: does this inequality hold with the given conditions? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The inequality doesn't hold. Imagine all $Y$'s and $X$'s are identically distributed and all $Y$'s are equal to each other. Then $\bar Y$ is a Bernouiili variable itself and is clearly not dominated by $\bar X$ since the latter is tightly concentrated around $p\in(0,1)$ .

Comment: Thanks for the response, this answers my question.

Comment: Independence seem like an essential property for Hoeffding/Chernoff type of techniques.